# How to open a multiple page PDF file as artboards in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pdf

I'm trying to open a PDF file with 7 pages and need to adjust each page in Illustrator CS6.  How do I open the PDF file in one single AI files with all artboards within it?

Answer (score 21):

There's this cool plugin:
http://aiscripts.com/open-multipage-pdf/

It's worked beautifully for me

Comment: Please explain more. Suppose the linked page is down. Then your answer is useless as it stands now ...

Comment: Illustrator can not really open all pdf pages, the script  mimics this functionality by opening one page at a time and duplicating the contents into a new document...it works on CS4-CC, win & mac

Comment: The link broke, who would have guessed? New URL: http://aiscripts.com/open-multipage-pdf/

Comment: This does work with CC15, fortunately for my sanity. Thank you, @CarlosCanto, for your plugin!

Comment: Thank you! Working without a problem on my Illustrator CS6.

Comment: worked as of March 2018 for me using CC 2018.

Comment: worked brilliantly with CC 2017

Answer (score 8):

**The Illustrator PDF Editing Method:**
Illustrator's open file dialog box allows you to open a specific page of the PDF document. When changes are made to a single page and saved, those changes are saved to the original PDF document overwriting only that page of the multi page PDF file. Aside from a global view of the document as art boards, this works for most cases.

**Other Methods:** Illustrator doesn't have a way to open a multi page PDF as an .ai file with multiple artboards. One way is with scripts and achieve a conversion or open PDF pages one by one and drag and drop them into a new .ai file presetted with the number of desired artboards.

Answer (score 8):

I forked and translated the original Multi-Page PDF Loader 4 AI v2.5 script to English, and added the ability to import .AI files.

I tested this and can successfully import multi-page documents as artboards.

[Multi-Page PDF Loader 4 AI v2.5.jsx (English)](https://github.com/arnaudin/ExtendScripts4AI-ID/blob/master/AI_Multi-Page%20PDF%20Loader%204%20AI%20v2.5.jsx)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2):

There is another script that has worked, in some cases better, for me. The interface is in chinese (i think), but is pretty self explanatory. Works in a similar matter to the script mentioned before:

[Multi-Page PDF Loader 4 AI v2.5.jsx](http://applia.tumblr.com/post/11606907861/multi-page-pdf-loader-4-ai-v2-5-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

You can place the multi page PDF as a link in Illustrator and change the pages using import options.

Just use `File > Place > Show Import Options`