# Open Multiple Pages in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cs6, artboard

I'm trying to open a catalog AI file with 32 pages and need to adjust each page in Illustrator CS6. How do I open the AI file in one single AI files with all artboards within it?

Comment: Hi Zaher, are you saying there are 32 different files each with 1 artboard or 1 file that should have 32 artboards (pages)? Your question is confusing since if you have 1 AI file then all of the graphics would be in that 1 file unless you're working with a PDF.

Comment: @AndrewH yest it's 32 different pages each has it's own artboard but it's an AI file not PDF. I'm sorry for the confusion but this is the file I got from my client which was designed by a previous Graphic Designer

Comment: @AndrewH 1 AI file includes multiple pages but when I open it via Illustrator it only allows me to open 1 page out of 32

Comment: I believe the file you're working with is a PDF file since AI files don't have pages. Check out this similar question - [How to open a multiple page PDF file as artboards in Illustrator CS6](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37235/how-to-open-a-multiple-page-pdf-file-as-artboards-in-illustrator-cs6).

Comment: @AndrewH thank you for the information and link. The script supports CS4 & CS5 I have CS6 won't make conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to open a multi-page PDF file in Illustrator since AI files do not have "pages".

**You can check out this script for CS5 & CC**:

[Convert PDF Pages to Illustrator Artboards](http://rwillustrator.blogspot.com/2011/03/convert-pdf-pages-to-illustrator.html)

> An AppleScript that would basically allow you to drop any multipage PDF file on it -- and it would turn it into a mutli-artboard Illustrator file, with all the PDF pages -- in one step! Being that the script is written in AppleScript, it will only run on MacOS.

Users report that this script works up to CS6 and CC.

**This script works for CS4**:

[Open Multi-Page PDF](http://aiscripts.com/open-multipage-pdf/)