# Illustrator CS5 Import/combine files as artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, cs5

I have about 8 PDF (not one PDF with multiple pages, each a single PDF with single pages), AI editable files. I have been searching around and playing around with illustrator, but haven't had any success, unless of course I want to copy and paste everything, but that is a pain and time consuming.

Is there anyway to import a file into an AI doc as an artboard?

Comment: See similar question [How to open a multiple page PDF file as artboards in Illustrator CS6](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37235/how-to-open-a-multiple-page-pdf-file-as-artboards-in-illustrator-cs6) and [Open Multiple Pages in Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61435/open-multiple-pages-in-illustrator/61438#61438)

Comment: @AndrewH thanks, but those are for a single PDF with multiple pages, I am trying to import multiple PDF's that have a single page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only 8 pages I would manually place the PDF's. You can place all of the PDF's in 1 swoop.

**Placing multiple files at once seems to only work in Illustrator CC***. See [Illustrator Help / 
Place multiple files | Illustrator CC](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/multiple-file-place.html).

1) Go to Object -> Artboards -> Fit to artwork bounds.

2) Go to File -> Place and select all of the PDFs to open.

3) Left click to place each of the PDF's.

4) Select the Artboard Tool (Shift+0) and click on each PDF. The artboard will now be the size of the PDF.

*The process works but earlier version of Adobe Illustrator will not be able to select multiple files at a time to place when going to File -> Place. For this process to work in earlier version you will need to do it one by one.

Comment: It wouldn't let me add them all at the same time, but that was fine doing it one at a time. However, the only thing is once added you can't make changes to the PDF file. You need to then click on `Embed`, then it will allow you to edit it as if it were the original PDF opened in AI

Comment: @Adjit it depends on how you import the PDF. When going to File -> Place, you have the option to link the PDF or not. If "link" is checked then you will not be able to edit the document. If unchecked, then you will be able to open the PDF and edit the document (You will have to release clipping mask and ungroup). However this may cause some issues (Illustrator warning box). I am not sure why you cannot place multiple PDFs at once, you should be able to.

Comment: Ahhh, ok didn't see that link thing. The CS5 file explorer is horrible... it's not user friendly at all and takes forever to navigate, and it also doesn't let me select multiple files. Maybe I just need to do an update

Comment: @Adjit I agree, I am not a fan of the file explorer as well. I didn't realize file place for multiple files is limited by the version of Illustrator. I checked the help files and I only see this feature for Illustrator CC. I am not sure about CS6.